# Understanding how to use the absolute function in a logarithmic function to open the integrals domain

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm taking a ODE class and one of the questions

$$y'= \dfrac{xy+x}{xy-y}$$

I have worked it down to $(y+1) - \ln(y+1) = (x-1) + \ln(x-1) + c$. The answer in the text book for the general solution has it worked down to $y - \ln(y+1) = x + \ln(x-1) + c$. I don't understand how this conclusion was reached and when I tried searching for the answer to this on an integral calculator the explanation was that; Apply the absolute value function to arguments of logarithm functions in order to extend the antiderivative's domain. What does this mean? Would really appreciate the help and thank you for your time.

Comment: I might be missing something, but I see only a difference in the form of the integration constant between the two solution formulas. As general ODE solutions this is equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start from your working

$$y+1 - \ln (y+1) = (x-1) + \ln (x-1) + c$$

$$y - \ln (y+1) = x + \ln (x-1) + c-2$$

Now, let $C=c-2$,

$$y - \ln (y+1) = x + \ln (x-1) + C$$

and we reach the textbook solution.

Comment: Ok so the constant subtract 2 results in another constant, thank you so much